# How do I earn medals to award my squaddies?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Enemy Within introduces the concept of medals -- minor, customizable bonuses that you can bestow upon worthy soldiers from the barracks.

However, such medals are limited quantity - how do you earn more?

I *believe* that you earn one International Service Medal for every council mission undertaken, but I have no idea about how to earn the "Defender's Medal" that I've already run into. (Perhaps something to do with the rookies dying? I expect a lot of rookies to die. C'est la XCom)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Ufopedia](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=XCOM:_Enemy_Within_DLC_(EU2012)) each medal is received in a different way, and there is a limitation on the total number of medals of each kind you can have on your live soldiers:

- **Urban Combat Badge** - +5 Defense when in cover or +5 Aim against enemies in full cover.
  Maximum of 5 medals issued. Requires completing an urban map mission?
- **Defender's Medal** - Never panic as result of allies getting wounded or killed or Medikits and Restorative Mists heal 2 HP more when used on this soldier.
  Maximum of 3 medals issued. Requires a soldier dying or being stabilized.
- **International Service Cross** - +2 Will per different nationality in the squad or +2 Aim per continent bonus XCOM has earned.
  Maximum of 2 medals issued. Requires a mission(s) outside your base's continent.
- **Council Medal of Honor** - Provides 10 Aim and Critical Chance if not within 7 tiles of an allied unit.
  Maximum of 2 medals. Complete Council missions.
- **Star of Terra**
  Maximum of 1 medal. Complete XCOM Base Defense mission.

I can confirm from my own experience that the info for all the first 4 seems to be correct.

The maximum number of medals refers to the number of medals in the medals pool + the number of medals pinned on **live** soldiers. So, when a soldier with a medal dies or is dismissed, a new medal can be received.

Comment: Hm. This info still looks a little complete. What does the limit refer to - i.e. a limit of 5 medals issued per game? Or up to 5 medals pinned to soldiers at any given time (and when one of them bite it, a new medal)?

Comment: I assume dismissing a soldier with medals also frees up the # of medals so new ones can be generated?

Comment: @RibsNGibs, yes.

Comment: +1.  I didn't know that there was a max limit to the number of medals in play in the game.  Would have liked to know that for the defender of the world achievement.